# Stackviews and dismissing a keyboard

Tags: view, keyboard, stack, dismiss

I am new to programming and new to this forum.. I have a problem with stack views. Once I had implemented stack views: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lgf0.png my code to dismiss keyboard stopped working. When I hit the text box the keyboard appears and I can enter values. When clicking outside the text box the keyboard remains. Without Stack views all is well.. Here is the code for dismiss keyboard:

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
                                                             }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {


       }

    // dismiss keyboard on touch outside textfield
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:   UIEvent?) {
    for txt in self.view.subviews {
        if txt.isKind(of: UITextField.self) && txt.isFirstResponder {
            txt.resignFirstResponder()
                                                                    }
                                  }
                                                                                    }
```

What am I doing wrong?? how do I get the keyboard dismiss function to work again while keeping stack views?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove everything in the `touchesBegan` function and just add `self.view.endEditing(true)` in it. I tried this with my textfield in UIStackView and this line does it all.

**Swift 4.1:**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```